# Html5 Web Application, find out if the mobile device is on Wireless (local network) or not?

Tags: javascript, html, navigator

Is there a good way, to find out, if the mobile device is on Wireless (local network) or not?

There is this javascript function navigator.onLine, but i'm not so happy with this function.

I will only detect, if the device is on wireless, and not on G4, G3, or edge...

Thanks for answer...
regards

Comment: What do you mean "local network" - any local network or a particular local network? Why do you care if the device is using Wi-Fi or Cellular? What about Ethernet?

Comment: Becouse if the device is on Cellular, Wi-Fi and it's only Edge, then the Web App has problem to load the manifest data. I'm looking for a solution, which handle this problem. So if de device is on Ethernet then it's going online, else it's standing offline. Also when there is a cellular network (G3,G4,E) it should run offline).

Comment: That sounds odd. Is that bug/feature documented anywhere?

Comment: No it's not a bug. It's my requirement! I want, that my Html5 Web Application only goes online, when it is on Ethernet. When not, it's should run offline.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check connection type (WiFi/LAN/WWAN) using HTML5/JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701328/how-do-i-check-connection-type-wifi-lan-wwan-using-html5-javascript)

Comment: No sorry, this navigation.conection is experimental, and not supported in chrome and orher browsers...