# How to check if the user is online using javascript or any library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, offline

I need some help on how I could check the internet connection using *Javascript* or *jQuery* or any library if available. cause i'm developing an offline application and I want to show a version if the user is offline and another version if the user is online.

For the moment i'm using this code :

```js
if (navigator.onLine) {
    alert('online');
} else {
    alert('offline');
}
```

But this is working very slow to detect. sometimes it's just connected to a network without internet, it takes 5 to 10 seconds to alert `false` (No internet).

I took a look at Offline.js library, but I'm not sure if this library is useful in my case. and I don't know how to use it

Comment: Could you define _very slow to detect_?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect that the Internet connection is offline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline)

Comment: @jmoerdyk to be fair, that post is 7 years old and technology has moved on leaps and bounds since then, not only that it looks as though the OP got their code from the answer by Edmhs on there.

Comment: That's right @JamieBarker I believe there is many ways on how to make that happens effectively.

Comment: @Stranger90 The answers are misleading because of your too broad question. What do you want to detect? If the user is connected to: internet, local network, or completely disconnected? If the user is disconnected, how would he be supposed to access the site, if it should be located on the intranet? Is the site installed on all computers??? O_O I think detecting internet connectivity resolves the problem, since if it isn't you should consider it is connected to intranet.

Comment: Please, improve your question being more specific of what you want. Why do you think Offline.js isn't useful on your case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline

Answer (score 16):

I just got this bit of code functionality from a [Mozilla Site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  if (navigator.onLine) {
    console.log('We\'re online!');
  } else {
    console.log('We\'re offline...');
  }
}, false);

window.addEventListener('online', function(e) {
  console.log('And we\'re back :).');
}, false);

window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) {
  console.log('Connection is down.');
}, false);
```

They even have a [link to see it working](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/navigator.onLine.html). I tried it in IE, Firefox and Chrome. Chrome appeared the slowest but it was only about half a second.

Comment: Mozilla Documentation: "In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions return true." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine that won't effectively detect the Internet being down, but rather your LAN being down.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I have already tried that, this doesn't work on page load ! it works only on internet state change

Comment: @Jamie Barker, because I was calling out that said article indicates it doesn't meet the OP's requirements. Hence the answer is incorrect. He even said it himself "sometimes it's just connected to a network without internet" :)

Comment: @dman2306. You've quoted out of context. Let's take the whole sentence instead of half of it: "_sometimes it's just connected to a network without internet, it takes 5 to 10 seconds to alert "false" (No internet)_". So it's alerting false when connected to a network without internet. This is **correct**. The OP's problem is the fact it's taking 5-10 seconds to compute the answer. I'm not saying my answer is correct, just that your understanding of the issue doesn't tie in with what the question states.

Comment: @Stranger90 The first function is a "as soon as the page is loaded" function, however I'm guessing you've tried it and it doesn't help?

Comment: @JamieBarker sorry for the misunderstading, but it doesn't detect offline when I'm connected to a network without connection.

Comment: @Stranger90 What do you mean by *connected to a network without connection*?

Comment: @falsarella He means a connected to a network without an _internet_ connection

Comment: @JamieBarker I've tried your solution and it doesn't work. i.e.: Loaded the page on my browser while online, then disconnected my wifi and load the page again,  still says, `online`

Comment: @PedroLobito Yeah, I'm guessing you're using Google Chrome? Read the first comment by dman2306...

Comment: @JamieBarker no, I'm using firefox.

Comment: @Pedro If I thought this was the correct answer I might actually be bothered to work out why it's not working for you. I took the code from Mozilla website and they have a website to test it on which works, so I can only suggest it's your setup which has problems.

Comment: @JamieBarker I was just informing you that it didn't work for me, you can do whatever you want with that info.

Comment: @PedroLobito Thank you. I'll lay the blame with the biological interface.

Answer (score 9):

i think you should try [OFFLINE.js](https://github.com/HubSpot/offline).. it looks pretty easy to use, just give it a try.

it even provides the option `checkOnLoad` which checks the connection immediately on page load.

> Offline.check(): Check the current status of the connection.
>
> Offline.state: The current state of the connection 'up' or 'down'

haven't tried it, would be nice to know if it works as intended.

**EDIT** took a little peak into the code, it uses the method with **FAILED XHR REQUEST** suggested in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline) SO Question

Comment: This project isn't actively maintained.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Detect that the Internet connection is offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189430/detect-that-the-internet-connection-is-offline) Basically, make an ajax request to something you know is likely to be up (say google.com) and if it fails, there is no internet connection.

Comment: Who says this is faster than `navigator.onLine`?

Comment: I took a look at that, that doesn't help a lot

Comment: @putvande It is more accurate, it checks for an INTERNET connection, not a NETWORK connection. From Mozilla docs: "In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions return true." So if I'm on my LAN, but the Internet connection is dead, navigator.onLine returns true. The sample answer would say false.

Comment: @Stranger90 Why doesn't that help?

Answer (score 3):

navigator.onLine is a property that maintains a true/false value (true for online, false for offline). This property is updated whenever the user switches into "Offline Mode".

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  function updateOnlineStatus(event) {
     document.body.setAttribute("data-online", navigator.onLine);
  }
  updateOnlineStatus();
  window.addEventListener('online',  updateOnlineStatus);
  window.addEventListener('offline', updateOnlineStatus);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// check if online/offline
// http://www.kirupa.com/html5/check_if_internet_connection_exists_in_javascript.htm
function doesConnectionExist() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var file = "http://www.yoursite.com/somefile.png";
    var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);

    xhr.open('HEAD', file + "?rand=" + randomNum, false);

    try {
        xhr.send();

        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome but can be faster!

Answer (score 3):

My solution is to grab a **very small image** (1x1), **not cached** and **always onLine**.

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
function onLine() {
alert("onLine")
}
function offLine() {
alert("offLine")
}
var i = new Image();
i.onload = onLine;
i.onerror = offLine;
i.src = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif';
});
</script>
<body>
```

---

Notes:

- Use a **local copy** of `jQuery` otherwise it won't work **offLine**.
- I've tested the code `onLine/offLine` and it works **without delay**.
- Works with all browsers, Desktop or Mobile.
- In case you wonder, there's no tracking made from Google Analytics as we don't use any arguments.
- Feel free to change the image, just make sure it doesn't get cached and it's small in size.

Answer (score 2):

Try utilizing `WebRTC` , see [diafygi/webrtc-ips](https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips); in part

> Additionally, these STUN requests are made outside of the normal
>   XMLHttpRequest procedure, so they are not visible in the developer
>   console or able to be blocked by plugins such as AdBlockPlus or
>   Ghostery. This makes these types of requests available for online
>   tracking if an advertiser sets up a STUN server with a wildcard
>   domain.

---

modified minimally to log "online" or "offline" at `console`

```js
// https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips
function online(callback){

    //compatibility for firefox and chrome
    var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
        || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
        || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;

    //bypass naive webrtc blocking using an iframe
    if(!RTCPeerConnection) {
        //NOTE: you need to have an iframe in the page
        // right above the script tag
        //
        //<iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
        //<script>...getIPs called in here...
        //
        var win = iframe.contentWindow;
        RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
            || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
            || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
        useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    }

    //minimal requirements for data connection
    var mediaConstraints = {
        optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
    };

    //firefox already has a default stun server in about:config
    //    media.peerconnection.default_iceservers =
    //    [{"url": "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]
    var servers = undefined;

    //add same stun server for chrome
    if(useWebKit)
        servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};

    //construct a new RTCPeerConnection
    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);

    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createDataChannel("");

    var fn = function() {};

    //create an offer sdp
    pc.createOffer(function(result){

        //trigger the stun server request
        pc.setLocalDescription(result, fn, fn);

    }, fn);

    //wait for a while to let everything done
    setTimeout(function(){
        //read candidate info from local description
        var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split("\n");
        // return `true`:"online" , or `false`:"offline"
        var res = lines.some(function(line) {
          return line.indexOf("a=candidate") === 0
        });
        callback(res);
    }, 500);
}

//Test: Print "online" or "offline" into the console
online(function(connection) {
  if (connection) {
    console.log("online")
  } else {
    console.log("offline")
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SignalR, if you're developing using MS web technologies.  SignalR will establish either long polling or web sockets depending on your server/client browser technology, transparent to you the developer.  You don't need to use it for anything else than determining if you have an active connection to the site or not.

If SignalR disconnects for any reason, then you have lost connection to the site, as long as your SignalR server instance is actually installed on the site.  Thus, you can use $.connection.hub.disconnected() event/method on the client to set a global var which holds your connection status.

Read up about SignalR and how to use it for determining connection states here...
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#clientdisconnect

Answer (score 1):

See *[How do I check connection type (WiFi/LAN/WWAN) using HTML5/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11701328/1064325)* answers:

- Rob W suggests [navigator.connection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.connection);
- Bergi suggests [`Windows.Networking.Connectivity` API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br207308.aspx) through [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh750310.aspx);
- Gerard Sexton suggests [Gmail approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11701449/1064325).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new **[Fetch API](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/)** which will trigger an error almost immediately if no network is present.

The problem with this is that the Fetch API has **[infant support](http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch)** at the moment (currently Chrome has the most stable implementation, Firefox and Opera is getting there, IE does not support it). There exists a **[polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch)** to support the fetch principle but not necessarily the rapid return as with a pure implementation. On the other hand, an offline app would require a modern browser...

An example which will try to load a plain text file over HTTPS to avoid CORS requirements (link is picked at random, you should set up a server with a tiny text file to test against - test in Chrome, for now):

```
fetch("https://link.to/some/testfile")
    .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status !== 200) {  // add more checks here, ie. 30x etc.
            alert("Not available");     // could be server errors
        }
        else
            alert("OK");
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        alert("No network");           // likely network errors (incl. no connection)
    });
```

Another option is to set up a **[Service worker](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/)** and use fetch from there. This way you could serve an optional/custom offline page or a cached page when the requested page is not available. Also this is a very fresh API.

Answer (score 0):

best one liner

```
console.log(navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline');
```