# How can i detect network change state(Lan connection to Wifi) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two connection **Lan** and **Wifi** in my pc.Wifi is automatically connect when lan connection is lost and vice-versa and **lan** Is my first priority.How can i detect network change state(i.e **lan connection to wifi**) in **javascript**.I have already use **navigator.onLine** and **offline.js** but this is not work for me.

Comment: Relevant info: [How do I check connection type (WiFi/LAN/WWAN) using HTML5/JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701328/how-do-i-check-connection-type-wifi-lan-wwan-using-html5-javascript)

Comment: And related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252403/is-there-any-way-to-detect-network-connection-type-using-javascript

Comment: how can i know it's wifi or lan

Comment: @jfriend00 it's work for if  two connection is lost but if  one connection is available it's is not detect