# how do I search for wifi networks with java script?

Tags: javascript, wifi

I am interested in making a app on my droid razr (just for me no app store) and I cant figure out how to search and sign onto a network.  This is for an app in development, I'm not just making something that signs in and out of a wifi network.

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701328/how-do-i-check-connection-type-wifi-lan-wwan-using-html5-javascript

Comment: i am on the droid razr right now its hard to see that profile i will check later. Thankyou