# what is best way in Angular 7 to detect internet network strength is 2G/3G/4G?

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to show images as per network strength(2g/3g/4g) type.
I want to perform this in angular. I want to optimize images.

Basically I need it to maintain and optimization of image loading. I am maintaining 2 type of images like if network is 2g then it will load thumbnail size(in KBs) images and if network is better(3g,4g) then it load  the actual size image(in MBs). Hope you understand my issue.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check connection type (WiFi/LAN/WWAN) using HTML5/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701328/how-do-i-check-connection-type-wifi-lan-wwan-using-html5-javascript)

Comment: i am not that your question will get you many responses. Perhaps include what are your findings for a potential solution, if you tried it and if it had worked or not?

Comment: Basically I need it to maintain and optimization of image loading. I am maintaining 2 type of images like if network is 2g then it will load thumbnail size(in KBs) images and if network is better(3g,4g) then it load  the actual size image(in MBs). Hope you understand my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Experimental **windows.navigator.connection**

it has a property type called **effectiveType** that can give you what type of connection the user have.

If you're using Angular, you can simply use it as:

```
const networkType = navigator.connection.effectiveType;
```

if you're using Angular with universal, you can add platform isPlatformBrowser

```
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

//inside your class constructor
isBrowser: any;
        constructor( @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: object) {
        this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
      }

//condition if code will run in client
if (this.isBrowser) {
    const networkType = navigator.connection.effectiveType;
}
```