# How to get browser network information in javascript?

Tags: javascript, frontend

[Network Information API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API) is an experiment feature.

Is there any existing way to get network information (e.g. 4g/5g/wifi, uplink/downlink, rtt, latency)? I would like to show the info in my React component for all popular browsers (chrome, firefox, safari).

```
const [networkInformation, setNetworkInformation] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
    setNetworkInformation({
      networkType: getNetworkType(), // returns like 4g/5g/wifi,
      uplink: getUplink(), // returns like 100 for 100kbps
      downlink: getDownlink(), // same as uplink
      rtt: getRtt(), // returns like 75 for 75ms
    });
  }, 2000);
}, []);

return (<div>{JSON.stringify(networkInformation)}</div>);
```

How to implement `getNetworkType`, `getUplink`, `getDownlink`, `getRtt`?

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for tools, software, or off-site resources is off-topic for StackOverflow. Please see [help/on-topic] for more info.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I am asking how to write javascript code without using MDN API, why would you think I am asking for tools/software?

Comment: Without the network information API there is only off-site tools and libraries left.

Comment: @evolutionxbox network information API is only available for chrome now, how can I get information for safari and firefox?

Comment: Check if [How do I check connection type (WiFi/LAN/WWAN) using HTML5/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11701328/2873538). But, It is not going to work on all browsers.

Comment: @AjeetShah what about [PerformanceResourceTiming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming#browser_compatibility) `window.performance.getEntriesByType('resource')`?

Comment: That may work as a workaround. Docs say: *An application can use the timing metrics to determine, for example, the length of time it takes to fetch a specific resource, such as an XMLHttpRequest, `<SVG>`, image, or script.* So, one may guess the type of connection based on the time it took to load the (a sample) resource. You can try.

Answer (score 0):

```
var connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;
var type = connection.effectiveType;
console.log(type);
```

`type` will be your connection type here.
To know more about this click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API)

Comment: I have tested it for safari and firefox, it does not return the info

Comment: Yes, There is no support for Safari and Firefox. This is an experimental feature.