# How to get access of connected network information in angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, cellular-network

```
{
    networkType: "2g" | "3g" | "4g" | "5g",
    connectionType: "wifi" | "bluetooth" | "ethernate" ,
    uploadingSpeed: "",
    downloadingSpeed: "",
    networkStrength : "",
    cellularOperator : "jio" | "vodafone" | "idea" | "others",
    networkAccuracy:""
}
```

I need this information which is described inside the object's key.

Suggest to me any library that will provide these details as described above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check connection type (WiFi/LAN/WWAN) using HTML5/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701328/how-do-i-check-connection-type-wifi-lan-wwan-using-html5-javascript)